# Convert and join multiple nested list of lists

Tags: python, list, nested

I have the following nested list of lists:

```
a = [[[[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758], [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909], [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779],
    [-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794], [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033], [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117],
    [-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723], [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897], [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838],
    [-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557], [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758]]], [[[-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684],
    [-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183], [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626], [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633],
    [-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809], [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773], [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548],
    [-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216], [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122], [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]]]
```

How would I go from that to:

```
a = [[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758], [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909], [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779], 
[-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794], [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033], [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117], 
[-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723], [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897], [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838], 
[-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557], [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758], [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684], 
[-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183], [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626], [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633], 
[-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809], [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773], [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548], 
[-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216], [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122], [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]
```

so basically remove the nested list and the double brackets at the beginning and end of each list. I've tried the following and ittertools without succes:

```
flatten = lambda list: [item for sublist in list for item in sublist]
```

Note: len(a) == 2

Many thanks!

Comment: In you particular case, `a[0][0]`?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans, @Arman, `len(a) == 2`

Comment: @falsetru you are right, didn't notice

Comment: @falsetru, exactly, that is why a[0][0] does not work in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job.

```
a = a[0][0] + a[1][0]
```

This can be extended as,

```
a = sum([a[i][0] for i in range(len(a))], [])
```

Comment: This seems to me to be the most sensible solution. It can also be adapted to work in case there are more than two elements easily.

Comment: exactly! if the format is consistent, this is the easiest way. @sphericalcowboy

Comment: can you guys comment the reasons for downvoting? this is not a "wrong" answer.

Comment: Using itertools might have some benefits over list concatenation (as mentioned in one of the other answers), but importing a module to do this seems a bit overkill to me if one is only dealing with `len(a) == 2`.

Comment: I improved it, in case these guys cannot figure out how to extend. And  @sphericalcowboy Thank you.

Comment: The order should be `a = sum([a[i][0] for i in range(len(a))], [])`, though, I think.

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Yes. In the case of lists, it worked but it is not the right way. :) I'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This indeed seems the most logic solution as it is not depended on other libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your lists aren't arbitrarily nested but you're just trying to go one level deeper, you could opt for something very simple like

```
a = [item for sublist in a for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist]
```

**Demo**

```
>>> a = [[[[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758], [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909], [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779],
[-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794], [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033], [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117],
[-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723], [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897], [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838],
[-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557], [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758]]], [[[-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684],
[-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183], [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626], [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633],
[-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809], [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773], [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548],
[-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216], [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122], [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]]]
>>> desired = [[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758], [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909], [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779], 
[-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794], [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033], [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117], 
[-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723], [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897], [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838], 
[-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557], [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758], [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684], 
[-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183], [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626], [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633], 
[-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809], [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773], [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548], 
[-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216], [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122], [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]

>>> a = [item for sublist in a for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist]
>>> a == desired
True
```

---

However as noted by falsetru you've got an empty level of nesting in your example, in which case the solution can be cleaned up nicely [as they have shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42421605/4686625).

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(xs[0] for xs in a))
```

Above is similar to: `a[0][0] + a[1][0] + ...` (without concatenation which cause list creation inbetween)

---

```
>>> a = [[[[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758],
...        [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909],
...        [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779],
...        [-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794],
...        [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033],
...        [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117],
...        [-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723],
...        [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897],
...        [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838],
...        [-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557],
...        [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758]]],
...      [[[-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684],
...        [-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183],
...        [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626],
...        [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633],
...        [-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809],
...        [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773],
...        [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548],
...        [-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216],
...        [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122],
...        [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]]]
>>> 
>>> import itertools
>>> import pprint
>>> b = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(xs[0] for xs in a))
>>> pprint.pprint(b)
```

result:

```
[[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758],
 [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909],
 [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779],
 [-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794],
 [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033],
 [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117],
 [-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723],
 [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897],
 [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838],
 [-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557],
 [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758],
 [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684],
 [-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183],
 [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626],
 [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633],
 [-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809],
 [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773],
 [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548],
 [-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216],
 [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122],
 [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[z for x in a for y in x for z in y]
```

And to prove it:

```
len([y for x in a for y in x]) == 21
```

You can see it properly using `pprint`:

```
pprint.pprint(a)
```

Ouput:

```
[[[[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758],
   [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909],
   [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779],
   [-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794],
   [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033],
   [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117],
   [-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723],
   [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897],
   [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838],
   [-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557],
   [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758]]],
 [[[-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684],
   [-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183],
   [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626],
   [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633],
   [-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809],
   [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773],
   [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548],
   [-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216],
   [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122],
   [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]]]

pprint.pprint([z for x in a for y in x for z in y])
```

Output:

```
[[-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758],
 [-79.4339722432865, -1.691845844583909],
 [-79.43397178076256, -1.691851284533779],
 [-79.43395283944169, -1.692053292637794],
 [-79.43395281911414, -1.692054736321033],
 [-79.43395535750368, -1.692093535418117],
 [-79.43390444734398, -1.69223087834723],
 [-79.43390428016939, -1.692231372437897],
 [-79.43374523144152, -1.692750043925838],
 [-79.4340256570161, -1.692750271834557],
 [-79.43402638260521, -1.69184588855758],
 [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684],
 [-79.43312765678151, -1.691845158387183],
 [-79.4331269307764, -1.692749541273626],
 [-79.43354270912953, -1.692749879305633],
 [-79.43364983051107, -1.692588468489809],
 [-79.4336510738479, -1.692585646334773],
 [-79.43371548446397, -1.692327269168548],
 [-79.43380554258165, -1.692094789340216],
 [-79.43380615195998, -1.692091785860122],
 [-79.43381375958064, -1.691845715849684]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the nested lists and join them.

A simple way:

```
def flatten1(list_of_lists):
  "Flattens one level of lists."
  result = []
  for sub_list in list_of_lists:
    result.extend(sub_list)
  return result
```

A clever way, exploiting the fact that you can add lists:

```
flatten1 = lambda(list_of_lists): sum(list_of_lists, [])
```

Now, you can `a[0] = flatten1(a[0])`.